# Google Chrome rotates anti-clockwise but should be clockwise

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

I have this CSS that I use for a triangle to be used for opening/closing a properties item, when the I click on the triangle I apply the "is-active" class and the triangle goes from pointing to the left to pointing down in a clockwise direction (works fine in IE, FireFox, Safari), but in the latest version of Chrome it goes anti-clockwise, now from what I've read it should only go anti-clockwise if the number is negative in the rotate() value.

Any ideas or has anyone seen this before?

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
 body {
    font-family: arial,verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.accordion-trigger:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-width: 5px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #666666;  
  border-right-width: 0;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);

}
 .accordion-trigger.is-active:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
  border-left-color: Black;
}
 .container 
 {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 18px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    -webkit-border: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;     
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="accordion-trigger" onclick="Rotate(this)"></div>        
</div>

<script>

function Rotate(entity) {
     $(entity).toggleClass("is-active");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've updated the code example with a mock up showing all the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem on the CSS: You are setting at the begining the rotate to `0` in all browsers except `-webkit-` browsers where you set `360` :

```
.accordion-trigger:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /*Change this to 0*/
  -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

Check this [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B9zEK/)

Comment: Yep that's the issue, I was advised to set that due to a bug in older versions of Safari, but I can live with that and would rather have it working correctly in Chrome.  Many thanks